# In Qualtrics I need longer boxes

Tags: javascript, html, qualtrics

I am using Qualtrics for my online survey. I have a problem with the length of text boxes. There are plenty of long items within my surveys, but the boxes do not have enough spaces. Thus, it makes the length of survey very long. Please see attached the snapshot. I need to decrease the space between scale poles and also increase the length of item boxes.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  The general idea of this site is for programmers to help each other.  It isn't a free programming service.

Answer (score 0):

just edit the width of our element in your CSS stylesheet, and the margin/padding left-right of your checkboxes... good luck !